# Envio de dados via Link (POST ou GET)

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, get

Bom dia meus caros, sou novo por aqui...

Antes de tudo, quero ressaltar que já li os tópicos que existe nesse fórum e não consegui resolver meu problema!

Meu problema, consiste em enviar apenas o id do banco de uma página PHP para outra que irá fazer o select através desse id e mostrar todos os dados do banco relacionado ao id enviado. Quero fazer isso através de um link, e não estou conseguindo.

```
<h2>
    <font size="5">
        <a href="mostrar.php" target="_blanck">
            <?=$linha['titulo']?>
        </a>
    </font>
</h2>
```

A ideia é enviar o id por essa linha de código ai.

Comment: Deve utilizar algo como `href="mostrar.php?id=<?= $linha['id'] ?>"`.

Comment: Essa linha é meu link, ou seja, ela mostra a descrição do link e teria que enviar o id teoricamente, porem eu não posso mostrar esse meu id na página. 
     <?=$linha['titulo']?> seria a descrição do meu link...

Comment: Isso existe: `target="_blanck"`? Não seria `target="_blank"`?

Comment: Erro de digitação amigo, fora isso alguma ajuda ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via `POST` você terá que fazer um form.

Via `GET` basta enviar o id no fim da url.

```
<a href="mostrar.php?id=<?=$linha['id']?>" target="_blank"><?=$linha['titulo']?></a>
```

A url fica assim:

```
mostrar.php?id=5
```

No arquivo `mostrar.php` você usa assim:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Mas é interessante antes você verificar se o `$_GET['id']` realmente existe:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = $_GET['id'];
}
```

Comment: Deu certo amigo, muito obrigado :)